# how to apply lookup inside mongodb field inside field?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, lookup

I have **Randomhospital** named  collection inside which there is a field named hospital which is of like this:

```
{
  "id": "GuDMUPb9gq",
  "Hospital Name": "UPHI",
  "Hospital City": "Gurgaon"
}
```

I also have another collection checklist in which there is a field **clinicId**.I want to apply lookup by matching **clinicId** with hospital object Id.

```
let pipeline=[{
            $lookup: {
                from: "Randomhospital",
                localField: "clinicId",
                foreignField: "hospital.id",
                as: "hospital_details"
            }
        }]
let query=await checklist.aggregate(pipeline)
```

but is not working as expected, it produces empty array? Could anyone suggest correction in code if any?

Answer (score 0):

You are making `lookup` from `checklist` to `Randomhospital`.

Make sure the id is proper.

Use

```
       $lookup: {
            from: "Randomhospital",
            localField: "clinicId",
            foreignField: "id",
            as: "hospital_details"
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need another variant of using `lookup` operator with **let** and **pipeline** [Check documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries)

Probably your solution will looks like next:

```js
let pipeline=[{
            $lookup: {
                from: "Randomhospital",
                "let": {"cid": "$clinicId"},
                "pipeline": [{
                  "$match": {
                    "$expr": {
                      "$eq": ["$hospital.id", "$$cid"]
                    }
                  },
                }]
                as: "hospital_details"
            }
        }]
let query=await checklist.aggregate(pipeline)
```